# create trigger on view that will allow insert for every column

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I create a trigger on this view that will allow to insert every column? 
If there is any need how would I proceed? Please let me know.

```
CREATE view trigger_view AS
SELECT p.topic project, p.description, t.name taskname, c.name coursename
FROM Course c join Course_Project cp on c.courseid = cp.courseid
    JOIN Project p on cp.projid = p.projid
    JOIN Task t on p.projid = t.projid
GROUP BY p.topic, p.description, t.name, c.name
```

Comment: Trigger on a select? What are you trying to do?

Comment: is trigger on the view, on that view that I provided above

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view.

Comment: Yeap, that is the idea.